# Apollo GraphQL DataLoader DynamoDb

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, dataloader

I'm new to GraphQL and am reading about N+1 issue and the dataloader pattern to increase performance.  I'm looking at starting a new GraphQL project with DynamoDB for the database.  I've done some initial research and found a couple of small NPM packages for dataloader and DynamoDb but they do no seem to be actively supported.  So, it seems to me, from my initial research, that DynamoDB may not be the best choice supporting an Apollo GraphQL app.

Is it possible to implement dataloader pattern against DynamoDb database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataloader doesn't care what kind of database you have. All that really matters is that there's some way to batch up your operations.

For example, for fetching a single entity by its ID, with SQL you'd have some query that's a bit like this:

```
select * from product where id = SOME_ID_1
```

The batch equivalent of this might be an `in` query as follows:

```
select * from product where id in [SOME_ID_1, SOME_ID_2, SOME_ID_3]
```

The actual mechanism for single vs batch querying is going to vary depending on what database you're using, it *may* not always be possible but it usually is. A quick search shows that DynamoDB has `BatchGetItem` which might be what you need.

Batching up queries that take additional parameters (such as pagination, or complex filtering) can be more challenging and may or may not be worth investing the effort. But batching anything that looks like "get X by ID" is always worth it.

In terms of finding libraries that support Dataloader and DynamoDB in particular, I wouldn't worry about it. You don't need this level of tooling. As long as there's some way of constructing the database query, and you can put it inside a function that takes an array of IDs and returns a result in the right shape, you can do it -- and this usually isn't complicated enough to justify adding another library.